# combineLatest alternative to combine or merge Observables

Tags: merge, rxjs, observable

I was under the impression `combineLast` was a good fit at first, but as I read the docs it seems it isn’t: “Be aware that `combineLatest` will not emit an initial value until each observable emits at least one value.”… And of course I hit exactly that exception. I tried `forkJoin` and `merge` in various combinations, but I can’t get it right.

The use-case is pretty straightforward, the method `someObs` returns `0` or more observables, over which I loop. Based on a value on the `SomeObs` object I push a newly constructed observable, `OtherObs[]`, to an `Array` of `Observable<OtherObs[]>`. This array "needs" to be merged into a single observable, and before returning it I’d like to do some transformations.

Specifically I’m having difficulty replacing the `combineLast` operator with something appropriate…

```typescript
public obs(start: string, end: string): Observable<Array<OtherObs>> {
  return this.someObs().pipe(
    mergeMap((someObs: SomeObs[]) => {
      let othObs: Array<Observable<OtherObs[]>> = [];

      someObs.forEach((sobs: SomeObs) => {
        othObs.push(this.yetAnotherObs(sobs));
      });

      return combineLatest<Event[]>(othObs).pipe(
        map(arr => arr.reduce((acc, cur) => acc.concat(cur)))
      );
    })
  );
}

private yetAnotherObs(): Observable<OtherObs[]> {
  /// ...
}

private somObs(): Observable<SomeObs[]> {
  /// ...
}
```

Comment: So what's your question, what you're trying to do or what doesn't work?

Comment: you can often work around the combineLatest() limitation by applying `startWith` to each of your inner observables so that they always immediately emit some initial value.

Comment: Fo me, the problem come from your method yetAnotherObs(). It's seems that the observables returned by this functions don't emit any value.
You could use any combination operators, but you have to make sure your observables emit something to proceed.
It would be great to have more details about what this function does.

Answer (score 16):

The "problem" of `combineLatest` is (like you said) that it "will not emit an initial value until each observable emits at least one value". But this is not a problem because you can use the RxJS operator [startWith](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/startwith.html).

So your observable gets an initial value and `combineLatest` works like a charme ;)

```typescript
import { of, combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { delay, map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

// Delay to show that this observable needs some time
const delayedObservable$ = of([10, 9, 8]).pipe(delay(5000));

// First Observable
const observable1$ = of([1, 2, 3]);

// Second observable that starts with empty array if no data
const observable2$ = delayedObservable$.pipe(startWith([]));

// Combine observable1$ and observable2$
combineLatest(observable1$, observable2$)
  .pipe(
    map(([one, two]) => {
      // Because we start with an empty array, we already get data from the beginning
      // After 5 seconds we also get data from observable2$
      console.log('observable1$', one);
      console.log('observable2$', two);

      // Concat only to show that we map boths arrays to one array
      return one.concat(two);
    })
  )
  .subscribe(data => {
    // After 0 seconds: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
    // After 5 seconds: [ 1, 2, 3, 10, 9, 8 ]
    console.log(data);
  });
```

[See example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-wjcrgm)